# Optimize Count query in MySql usual practice

Tags: mysql

I need to count the records from the table where the column = "value". I only have one column in my where clause, and only need to count from one table. The table can grow in big sizes.  What's the optimize way of doing the count query?

options so far:
1. column not index, full table scan 
2. column was index, non-unique key lookup but then there's only 3 possible values so not optimal to use an index 
3. create a summary table, with triggers to populate the count, then query from this table but this will need a lot of work. Each time there will be a new stats needed, will need to create new triggers

Any other approach? Any preferred way of doing it? Which options do you usually do in your project?

Comment: "Practical" already implies that it will depend on the specific situation. We cannot list all the situations that you might encounter when doing this decision, even your option 1 has practical use cases. If you get (or going to get) the result slowing than you need, you need a different solution. We do not know if you are trying to count the number of children infront of your self-driving car or the number of employees in the end-of-year-report. Also, generally, people are underestimating what "big in sizes" practically means.

Comment: Thanks! For now, we still not encountering any slowness in result as the data size is small.  It's basically a transaction table which can grow in sizes when we have more customers purchases.  So we need to like get statistics from table, so thinking if which one is the option to choose from.

Comment: As I said, it depends on your requirements. 2 is basically the "correct way" (assuming your data model is correct), as alternatives (and there are other ways than 3) usually need to duplicate data. You make a compromise for performance reasons. If you need to do this depends on your requirements. If you need a report once a week, let it take 20s. Unless your boss wants it in 15s. If you display "Costumers also bought..." on your site, it can't take 20s, but doesn't need to be accurate. An inventory count needs to be exact and fast (and still usually works with indexes until it doesn't).